# Using berkshelf with ChefDK and the Chef Supermarket

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf, chefdk

I'm brand new to Chef and linux so forgive me if this questions is blatantly obvious or if I'm doing this horribly wrong. So far I have managed to set up a basic standalone Chef server on an Ubuntu 14.04 instance that is running in my network. I setup a Ubuntu desktop on a VM that I have running on my computer. I've been going through tutorials and so far the process I use to get cookbooks from the Chef supermarket up to my Chef server is that I download them to my chef workstation on ubuntu desktop and then upload with the corresponding demands. However, a question I have is that for some more robust cookbooks such as Node.js or MongoDB when I download them to my workstation and then try to upload them to my chef servers it fails. It says that it can't upload properly because it is missing certain dependencies it has. I know that this is the exact  use case berkshelf is used for. However, I have no idea how to use it in relation to cookbooks I get from the supermarket. I tried to cd to my directory where my downloaded cookbooks are and run berks install but it gives me errors. Am i doing this wrong or is there a whole other process I should look into? Sorry for possible bad grammar and if this question is painfully simple.

Comment: have you tried googling how to use berkshelf with chef?

Answer (score 1):

Try following one of a bunch of available tutorials on how to use Berkshelf with Chef, such as the one at http://cloudacademy.com/blog/berkshelf-manage-chef-cookbooks/.

Comment: It gives me an error "Error retrieving universe from source: http://api.berkshelf.com" and then proceeds witha  BadResponse Http error have you experienced this before?

Comment: @Anders Sounds like you are using a really really old version of Berkshelf. Install the latest chefdk package instead, this will give you everything you need to use Chef. Believe me its a lot lot easier

Comment: @Anders Berkshelf used to be a separate community maintained tool. Chef have now taken it under their wing. Part of this change is the introduction of the chef supermarket who URL endpoint is: https://supermarket.chef.io.This is why you're getting bad HTTP responses. The old site is gone.